# Infinite scrolling background

Tags: html, css

i have somewhat achieved infinite scrolling background using background position property.But the problem is i've given the value background-position:0 200px
in the keyframes,after moving downwards to 200px the background image restarts its movement from the beginning.I don't want that to happen,it should scroll infinitely without any hiccups. how to do it?

here is the code.

html:

```
 <div id="cloud-scroll"></div>
```

css:

```
       #cloud-scroll {
        width: 275px;
       height: 183px;
       background: url(http://www.html5andbeyond.com/3t-JAiBqopF/uploads/2014/10/clouds-full.png);
      background-size:cover;
      -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 20s linear infinite;
      animation: backgroundScroll 20s linear infinite;
       }

       @-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
          from {background-position:0;}
          to {background-position:0 200px;}
       }

      @keyframes backgroundScroll {
       from {background-position:0;}
        to {background-position:0 200px;}
       }
```

Comment: Have a linear movement with a value, where the background eventually matches up (you can use the height of the background image)

Answer (score 0):

You should use background-repeat and set your background image such that when it's repeated vertically ( or horizontally, if that's what you are doing ), it is seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is 183px tall, so you should use 183px in your animation.

```
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
   from {background-position:0;}
   to {background-position:0 183px;}
}
```